# django upload file, process pandas and download as csv

Tags: python, django, csv, pandas

I built an app which allows the user to upload a file.
On the other hand,
I have some python script which takes a text file, convert it to CSV and do pandas. This script works perfectly when running in the terminal. 
Now I want to apply that python script to the file upload in Django and show that file in httpResponse and make available to download it.

### python script

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('raw_df.txt', delimiter = '\t' , usecols=['Sample','Cohort','Metabolite Name','Intensity'])
df = df[df['Cohort'].str.contains("std")]
df = df.groupby(['Cohort', 'Metabolite Name'])['Intensity'].sum().reset_index()
df = df[['Cohort','Intensity']]
c = 'Cohort'
s = df.set_index([c, df.groupby(c).cumcount() + 2]).Intensity
df =    s.unstack().add_prefix('Intensity').reset_index()
df.to_csv()
print df;
```

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

from uploads.core.models import Document
from uploads.core.forms import DocumentForm


def home(request):
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'core/home.html', { 'documents': documents })

def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'core/model_form_upload.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

Models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
```

template-upload page

```
   {% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>

  <p><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Return to home</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Wrap your file processing in a method:

   ```
   import csv
   import pandas as pd

   def process_file(file_handle):
       df = pd.read_csv(file_handle, delimiter = '\t' , usecols['Sample','Cohort','Metabolite Name','Intensity'])
       df = df[df['Cohort'].str.contains("std")]
       df = df.groupby(['Cohort', 'Metabolite Name'])['Intensity'].sum().reset_index()
       df = df[['Cohort','Intensity']]
       c = 'Cohort'
       s = df.set_index([c, df.groupby(c).cumcount() + 2]).Intensity
       df =    s.unstack().add_prefix('Intensity').reset_index()
       return df.to_csv()
   ```
2. in your view:

   ```
   ... 
   if form.is_valid():
   document = form.save()
   # call to the new method
   csv = process_file(document.document)
   response = HttpResponse(csv, content_type='text/csv')
   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=result.csv'
   return response
   ...
   ```

Comment: After doing this I got IOError: File file_handle does not exist.

Comment: please debug: make sure that `document.document` is not None and it has a `read()` method. According to [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) `read_csv()` should support a `FileField`

Comment: Hi i tried this only with a slightly different file input (a text file) and processed in a different way: `def process_file(f):
    file=open(f, "r");
    x=file.read();
    .....
    new_file=open("result.txt", "w");
    return(new_file.write(x));
    file.close()
`

everything else is the exact same and I receive the error that the file is incorrect ... invalid file: `<FieldFile: documents/polymer_model_LtcOE0j.txt>`